# I can't submit any options in CUTIE command line tool

Tags: python

I can't submit answer or mark checkboxes.

```
import cutie

opcje_wybory = ["Duże Litery", "Liczby", "Znaki Specjalne"]

opcje_indeksy = cutie.select_multiple(opcje_wybory)
opcje = [opcje for opcje_index,
        opcje in enumerate(opcje_wybory)
        if opcje_index in opcje_indeks]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

On the last line you are missing the `y` in `opcje_indeks`. I think you meant to spell `opcje_indeksy`.

```
import cutie

opcje_wybory = ["Duże Litery", "Liczby", "Znaki Specjalne"]

opcje_indeksy = cutie.select_multiple(opcje_wybory)
opcje = [opcje for opcje_index,
    opcje in enumerate(opcje_wybory)
    if opcje_index in opcje_indeksy] # <-- here `opcje_indeksy`
```